# .NET Core HttpContext.Request.Headers.Remove() doesn't work unless the Headers are enumerated first

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-5

I try to remove a header from the `httpContext.Request.Headers` by running the following statement:

```cs
httpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("HeaderName");
```

This doesn't do anything, the header is still present in the `IHeaderDictionary`. After trying for a while I noticed that when I convert the `IHeaderDioctionary` to a `List` first, the header is successfully removed.

```cs
_ = httpContext.Request.Headers.ToList();
httpContext.Request.Headers.Remove("HeaderName");
```

Another way to do it is to first check if the key exists. the `.ContainsKey()` method enumerates the `IHeaderDictionary`, which makes the `.Remove()` work.

```cs
if (context.Request?.Headers?.ContainsKey("HeaderName") ?? false)
{
  context.Request.Headers.Remove("HeaderName");
}
```

Now while my code runs and does what I want it to do, I wonder why it is necessary to first enumerate the `IHeaderDictionary`? And is there a better way to achieve this?

To add some more context, here's how I pass the `httpContext` to my method in the `Startup.cs`:

```cs
// Startup.cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultScheme = "default";
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "default";
        })
        .AddPolicyScheme("default", "default", options =>
        {
            options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
            {
                // in this async method I remove the header
                return schemeService.GetSchemeAsync(context).Result;
            };
        })
}
```

Comment: This link may be useful: http://bercocano.blogspot.com/2019/11/understanding-aspnet-middleware.html. See section "Creating Request-Editing Middleware". BR

Comment: Thanks for the article. In the "Creating Request-Editing Middleware" example, he first checks `httpContext.Request.Headers["User-Id"].Any()`, which enumerates the `IHeaderDictionary` (same as my `.ToList()` or `.ContainsKey()`). While this is for sure a better way to do it, it doesn't answer why this is necessary.

Comment: I guess looking into the source for related code will give an explanation for this behaviour. I didn't have the time yet to do this myself. BR

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I've experienced the same issue recently so just posting the answer for anybody who may face it too.

The problem I had was in a custom .NET Core middleware for removing an HTTP header from `HttpContent.Request.Headers`. It worked correctly locally and on a Linux app service in Azure, but did not work on a Windows app service. Both app services were configured to use .NET Core 7.

Middleware code was as simple as that, note that the headers collection is not enumerated before calling the `.Remove()` method:

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext httpContext)
{
   httpContext?.Request.Headers.Remove("HeaderName");

   await _next(httpContext);
}
```

The root cause of this issue is the method `IHeaderDictionary.Remove()` that **behaves differently in Kestrel and HTTP.sys environments prior to .NET 8.0**:

- Kestrel always loads all headers and the removal operation works just fine without any collection enumerations
- HTTP.sys lazy-loads the headers collection and it causes a side-effect for headers with default values (Connection, Accept-Language, Accept-Encoding, etc.): if header value is not explicitly loaded before an attempt to remove it, then it is skipped and nothing gets removed. This is why calling `.ContainsKey()`, `Headers["HeaderName"]` or `.ToList()` as described in the question "resolves" the problem - it just makes HTTP.sys to load the real header value and then all conditions inside `.Remove()` are passed and the header is removed correctly.

Here is the related GitHub issue from **aspnetcore** repository with detailed explanation: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/43230. The issue has been fixed in .NET 8.0 and newer.